# Interact with custom UI element in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have problem interact with custom UI element. I have a custom modal window which is displayed when I hover mouse over the object and then I want to disappear it when mouse leaves modal window area but I can't find solution how to do it.
[Game Objects in the hierarchy and canvas inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy9ts.png)

I searched on the internet, I tried it with raycasters but its not working or maybe I doing something wrong.

This is how I call Script ModalWindowScript when is mouse over object so I can somehow interact with UI elements.

```
    [SerializeField] GameObject uIModalWindow;
    private void Start()
    { 
        uIModalWindow.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
        uIModalWindow.transform.position = mousePos;
        uIModalWindow.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        uIModalWindow.AddComponent<ModalWindowScript>();
    }
```

Expected result is that modal window will disappear when mouse will leave the modal window area. But actual status is that I can't find out how to communicate with UI.

[HoverOverObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5ZWh.png)
[ModalWindowScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hclZk.png)

Comment: Just to be clear, you have 2 objects. One you hover on the first object, which has ModalWindowScript attached, object 2 should be activated, correct?

Comment: Hello @FredrikSchön, this code that you can see is First script called HoverOverObject which is attached to one object and when mouse exits object area then is attached script component to uiModalWindow game object.

Comment: I don't think OnMouseEnter works on just any UI element, [read docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html). You'll have to implement the events yourself or find another solution. Maybe add a button?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working - hold on.

Comment: @FredrikSchön I know it not works for UI elements, this class is just for evoking this UI element when mouse is over some basic game object, It will call ModalWindowScript. And thanks I will try your solution bellow

Comment: [Remember to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your issue, or feedback if / why it didn't work! :)

Comment: Don't worry, I know how it works, I just didn't have time to try your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the IPointerEnterHandler & IPointerExitHandler interface to get this kind of solution to get the proper events:

```
public class HoverOverObject : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler

    [SerializeField] GameObject uIModalWindow;
    private void Start()
    { 
        uIModalWindow.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData e)
    {
        var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
        uIModalWindow.transform.position = mousePos;
        uIModalWindow.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData e)
    {
        uIModalWindow.AddComponent<ModalWindowScript>();
    }
}
```

Note changed code: Added Interfaces, Changed name of methods, Changed accessibility from private to public on methods.

Comment: no its not working at all, nothing happens when I exit modal ui area. And I also edit the issue. I added pictures of classes. Because I need this code for ModalWindowScript, HoverOverObject is enabled when is mouse over basic non UI ```   object and when mouse exits mouse area private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        uIModalWindow.AddComponent<ModalWindowScript>();
    }``` then I want to add this script to take care of UI behavior and close it when mouse is out of modal window

Comment: Basically, just add the interfaces on the classes where you want to trigger OnPointerEnter/Exit, regardless of on which components should call which etc.

Comment: Or do you mean that you get no effect when using the interfaces? Make sure that "raycast target" isn't disabled.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant. Where I can find "raycast target"? In the canvas inspector?

Comment: They're component specific, so for instance on a Text component you find it in the bottom here: [link to image](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/UI_TextInspector.png)

Comment: I would like to do it for the whole modal window if it is possible. I'll check if I have something like this in the parent for modal window