# How to delete dynamically loaded gameobjects from a List in Untiy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list that loads its content dynamically. The Elements of the List are buttons that are being transformed into gameobjects. For every object in the user list a new Element is created. Now I want to be able to delete the Element along with the button itself, when the button is pressed, where each Element has its own dynamically created delete button. I tried putting a box collider with an OnMouseDown Event, however onMouseDown is never called.

```
public void ShowLectures()
{
    foreach (var course in selectedCourses)
    {
        AddMoreButton();
    }
}

public void AddMoreButton()
{
    GameObject button = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
    button.transform.SetParent(panel.transform, false);
    button.layer = 5;
    button.SetActive(true);
}

public void OnMouseDown()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Is it UI elements? The button etc

Comment: Yes these are all ui elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `OnMouseDown` is not called on the created `Button` but in your case rather on the GameObject your script is attached to.

Then

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

the same way would destroy the GameObject your script is attached to, not the instantiated `button` GameObjects.

---

Since you commented that you are using a [`UI.Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html) component rather add it to the [`onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) event as a callback when the `Button` is instantiated :

```
public void AddMoreButton()
{
    GameObject button = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabButton);
    button.transform.SetParent(panel.transform, false);
    button.layer = 5;
    button.SetActive(true);

    // get the Button on the button object or any child
    var buttonInstance = button.GetComponentInChildren<Button>();

    // add a callback to destroy the button gameObject
    // () => {} is a lambda expression
    buttonInstance.onClick.AddCallback(()=>{ Destroy(button); });
}
```

---

A little hint: In case the `Button` is already on the same GameObject anyway you should rather change the prefab type itself to `Button` like e.g.

```
public Button prefabButton;
```

and than simply use

```
public void AddMoreButton()
{
    Button button = Instantiate(prefabButton, panel.transform);
    button.gameObject.layer = 5;
    button.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    // add a callback to destroy the button gameObject
    // () => {} is a lambda expression
    button.onClick.AddListener(()=>{ Destroy(button.gameObject); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a gameobject with an OnMouseDown, I'd probably create a Button instead and binding an event to it:

```
 var closeButton = /* Dynamically create button */
 closeButton.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(HandleCloseClick);

 void HandleCloseClick() {

     Destroy(gameObject);
 }
```

You can, however, do the architecture you've already implemented - you just need to implement [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html).

[Here's an answer describing how to implement & use the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940136/interact-with-custom-ui-element-in-unity/55942615#55942615).

Check the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) for instructions on how to use each event (Mouse Down, Up, Enter, Exit)

Comment: Note that this would still `Destroy(gameObject)` ... `gameObject` (the GameObject that script is attached to) is not what you want to destroy but rather the instantiated `button` GameObject ;)

Comment: Oh? `where each Element has its own dynamically created delete button`. I figured this was the object OP wanted to Destroy. The title mentions a list as well, but it doesn't exist in the question, but that's just a line before the Destroy, worst case.